# Clustering using correlation of residuals

Tags: correlation, clustering, linear-model

I have worked out a naive approach for clustering different variables, and I wonder what better approaches are there. I have data with many more dimensions (variables) than observations (samples), and I wish to cluster the variables by their correlation. However, the observations correspond to different groups, for example treatment and control. If I just calculate the correlation coefficient, all variables that go up in one group will have a positive correlation, and that is not what I intend; I want to cluster them by within-group effects and disregard between-group effects.

To give you a specific example: variables are abundances of certain substances in the serum of patients. Serum samples are the observations, and each serum sample is associated with a number of abundances (for example, abundances of amino acids, cytokines etc.). There are, say a hundred observations (serum samples), each associated with the same 1000 variables (abundances). I want to see which abundances are correlated: for example, which cytokines are correlated with which amino acids.

The approach that I am taking is to fit a simple linear model which explains the effect of various groups and correlate the residuals from the model. This heuristic works in the sense that it gives "reasonable" (in terms of biology) grouping of the variables, for example it clusters genes with similar functions.

Consider this example in R.

```
groups <- factor( rep( c( "a", "b" ), each= 50 ) )
set.seed( 123 )
x1 <- rnorm( 100 )
x2 <- rnorm( 100 ) # not correlated with x1 yet
x3 <- x1 + rnorm( 100 ) # positively correlated with x1
# simulate group effect
x1 <- x1 + rep( c( 0, 2 ), each= 50 )
x2 <- x2 - rep( c( 0, 2 ), each= 50 )
x3 <- x3 - rep( c( 0, 2 ), each= 50 )
```

Now, x1 and x2 appear negatively correlated (although within each group there is no correlation), and x1 and x3 appear not correlated at all (although within each group there is a positive correlation):

[image]

Then, I calculate the residuals:

```
x1r <- lm( x1 ~ groups )$residuals
x2r <- lm( x2 ~ groups )$residuals
x3r <- lm( x3 ~ groups )$residuals
```

The situation now is very much different and much more what I intend:

[image]

My question is this: what would be a statistically more appropriate way of achieving the same? Note that neither of x1, x2 or x3 can be treated as independent variables or response variables -- they are merely correlated, without a given as to which one is determines which other. My ultimate goal is to create clusters of variables that are correlated after removing the effects of the groups.

Comment: Your terminology is perceived confusing. What you call `samples` is more apt to call "cases", "observations", "data units" or "data points". Given that, what is `clusters of variables` for you? Are the clusters groups of cases or groups of variables?

Comment: I have now added a specific example that is maybe clearer. And yes, by `clusters of variables` I do mean clusters of variables rather than clusters of samples.

Comment: If you need to get rid of the bimodal group heterogeneity, why not compute separate covariance matrix for each group, then average the matrices in one, and then, if needed, convert that into correlation matrix.

Comment: I have simplified my case. In reality, the model fitted can be a mixture of factors and continuous variables. The point is to account for the controlled variables and calculate the correlations on the unexplained portion of the variance.

Comment: You may do what you did: save residuals of the ANOVA of each your Xs by Group (+ covariate). Use Multivariate ANOVA to process your Xs in a batch.